# Parsing JSON that can be one of multiple classes

Tags: apex, json

IS there a way to parse JSON without knowing exactly what the class is.

For example:

I have JSON in the following format:

```
{"id":"381f05c5-b02e-4aa1-8def-c54a6026764a","feature":"Feature1","settings":{"dateFilter":"Today","startDate":1547701200000,"endDate":1547701200000}}
```

But it could also be of the format

```
{"id":"0cf1378a-3a38-491e-9a22-926140a2a562","feature":"Feature2","settings":{"objectId":"addfg1231ds"}}
```

The settings depends on what is saving. IS there any way that I can parse that JSON without parsing the settings as well? That way I can know from the feature which class to use to parse the settings. I dont think that can be done though.

So can anyone else offer a solution?

Comment: You can have a wrapper class to consist of `settings` attribute with all possible attributes applicable for it. And then while deserializing the JSON, you get only those attributes which are available in the JSON. Once deserialized, you can use the values from `settings` as needed.

Comment: Thought about that alright but its not really feasible moving forward. it would get out of hand

Comment: Well, if you don't want to parse `settings` at all, you can just ignore it in your wrapper class. But if you need that at any later point, it is recommended that you have it in the same wrapper class and depending on the values being parsed, take actions as needed. In other cases, you will need to utilize `JSON.createParser(...)` to identify if the JSON consists of particular keyword and then act upon it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can certainly just use `JSON.deserializeUntyped` and get a `Map<String, Object>`.

```
String payload = '{"id": ...}';
Map<String, Object> data = (Map<String, Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(payload);
```

You can set up a `Parser` interface which accepts a `Map<String, Object>` and acts on it. Then your implementations (named in your feature attribute) can be instantiated at run time.

```
interface Parser
{
    void doStuff(Map<String, Object> data);
}
class Feature1 implements Parser
{
    void doStuff(Map<String, Object> data)
    {
        String dateFilter = (String)data.get('dateFilter');
        // further processing
    }
}
class Feature2 implements Parser
{
    void doStuff(Map<String, Object> data)
    {
        String objectId = (String)data.get('objectId');
        // further processing
    }
}
```

You can then use the static `Type.forName` and instance `Type.newInstance` methods, along with casting, to get a `Parser` and call your `doStuff` method (which you will hopefully rename).

```
String payload = '{"id": ...}';
Map<String, Object> data = (Map<String, Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(payload);
Type parserType = Type.forName((String)data.get('feature'));
if (parserType != null)
{
    Parser parser = (Parser)parserType.newInstance();
    parser.doStuff(data.get('settings'));
}
```

Comment: Im having a problem. I added a featureName to the JSON. and in there I gave it a value that is the name of Feature2. But the line: Type parserType = Type.forName((String)data.get('featureName')); comes back empty.

Comment: You have to actually have a class by that name. If you are using inner classes you would need to prefix it with `OuterClass.`.

Comment: They are Inner classes. Ive never used OuterClass before. Can you tell me where I prefix it? A quick google doesnt bring up anything obvious

Comment: You were supposed to pick up on it being the name of whatever top level class you have which contains the inner classes. I do not know the name of it, so I used something I hoped would make sense. If you have a top level class of `Foo` and an inner class of `Bar`, you would get its type doing `Type.forName('Foo.Bar')`. So if you have `"feature": "Bar"`, you would need to do `Type.forName('Foo.' + feature)`.

Comment: Ah okay. Whoops. I thought you were using OuterClass as a keyword there. Sorry about that. I got it now. Thanks so much. This is a big help